# how to check if aggregation is possible or not?

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate

I have this code which aggregates the data across all the columns if possible, if there is no possible aggregation, it gives an error stating nothing to aggregate.

is it possible to run a check/put condition before i allow aggregation, to avoid the error.

This way system will only run the aggregate command if there is scope for aggregation else original data is good in its form

```
aggregate(Amt~UNIT_L+ACCT_DT+CURRENCY,data, sum)
```

Comment: Does "no possible aggregation" mean no category has more than one element?

Comment: What does `nrow(data)` return?

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).